# Menu in Title Bar

Tags: unity

Internally, how does Unity determine which widgets in an application are part of the menu (file, edit, etc.)? Is there a attribute in GTK that determines what's part of an application's menu bar?

Also, do applications need to be modified in some non-standard way to work like this? I've noticed that when I download Firefox from Mozilla, there is no menu bar shown, but the Ubuntu build of Firefox has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gtk application defines what should be in the menus at the top of its window and specifies what functions should be run when each is selected. The toolkit then implements those instructions using X. That's the design of gtk (and other toolkits).

If you are wondering about the toolbar appearing on the top of the screen rather than at the top of the application window, the application has the same design, but a small change has been made to gtk to intercept the drawing of the application menus, and the drawing instructions are instead relayed over the session dbus to Unity which handles the drawing and signaling associated with those menus. As I recall there's an environmental variable you can set to disable this behavior.